# How can I position a WordPress sidebar above all page content?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to make it so the product filter options in an ecommerce store I've built are displayed above the content like an inline-block above all the products displayed on each shop page? Please visit this link for reference: http://nicklisauskasdesign.com/index.php/product-category/womens-bracelets/

These product filter options are widgets in WordPress's sidebar area. Can someone please help me position the sidebar above the content and make it full width regardless of screen size?

Comment: Don't link to your site, bring the code here.  Otherwise, this question no value to future visitors - once the site is fixed, down, etc.  Show the code *from your template*, not the rendered HTML.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This really isn't a question with a quick answer. You will probably want to hire a developer to accomplish this.

I don't think it will be very difficult to do for someone who has access to the wp-admin and theme files, but more than can be answered in this forum.